# Need help creating a T-SQL script that displays Results of File, but at random spots in a SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, file

I have a massive script that I would like to have certain parts of the scripts "Results to File" (or any kind of file). I know of the Results to File button, but since this is a massive script with only certain data that I want to be placed inside multiple text files. I do not want to add any special features like BCP or OSQL.

```
print 'Logfile usage:'
dbcc sqlperf(logspace)

print 'Filestats db Testdb:'
dbcc showfilestats
```

I need the following two commands to print to two different text files located on the `C:\` drive. The files are not located in the same part of the script. Yes, I can put them next to each other, but I want other parts of the script to print as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a single monolithic script? (Guess: yes.) How are you submitting it to SQL Server? (Guess: via SSMS)

Comment: Using SSMS as a query to start with and if I can get it to do what I want it will turn into a SQL Job and run every month to keep maintenance for the SQL databases that it is checking.  It is Monolithic, one giant script that creates tables, compares tables, and does a lot more, but I just need to know how to have it output files to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring the use of the `sp_OA%` procedures mentioned by @Clay (sheesh, they haven’t deprecated those yet?), or building CLR routines to do this for you, what you want cannot be done when running a single script from SSMS.

Based on your comments, my recommendation for a long-term plan is:

1) Split it into several scripts, with an eye towards each script’s output writing to it’s own output file

2) Turn each of those into a stored procedure

3) Build a master procedure that calls each of them in turn

4) Use this master procedure when you’re running from SSMS and want a single call to run everything. Sadly, any output generated can only be directed to one output destination.

4a) When you truly need distinct output, call each proc in turn, resetting the “File Output” settings for each call. Not efficient, but it would work option.

5) When you get around to configuring this as a SQL Agent job, ditch the “master” procedure and configure each “sub” procedure as it’s own job step, configured with it’s own output file. This is fussy and a bit complex to set up, but SQL Agent does support it. As a bonus, with some effort you can get SQL Agent to send the files as email attachments to whomever they need to go to.

Depending, you just might be better off making the complex job now.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily run these from the command line and pipe results out to text files via powershell or even just sqlcmd.

**SQLCMD:**

The -i is your input file, the -o is your output file

```
sqlcmd -U**** -P ******* -S yourserver -d yourdatabase
    -i "path to your script.sql" -o "path to your output file.txt"
```

**PowerShell:**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "path to your script.sql" | Out-File
    -filePath "path to your output file.txt"
```

Comment: They need to have different output sets generated by a single script/batch written to two or more separate files.

Comment: I looked at the SQLCMD, but it is not one sql script that needs to output. The script is big an creates tables and drops tables. Verifies how much the logs are holding and comparing the logs after it kills the temp logs. Verifying that the Database is getting maintained. The data in the text files will be used to report the update to the management staff.

Comment: Ahhh, got it, yeah, that's a different story then.